# Symfony cannot install new bundles because of composer permission issue

Tags: composer-php, symfony-3.4

While try to install new bundles into my project composer issue happens which is regarding permission, issue follows

```
Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.


[Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException]                                                                                                                 
Failed to copy "/var/www/html/myProject/vendor/sensio/distribution-bundle/Composer/../Resources/skeleton/app/check.php" to "bin/symfony_requirements" because target file could not be opened for writing.
```

Thank you...

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Does the target file already exist? Did you check the permissions for its folder?

Answer (score 2):

You have wrong permissions on file `bin/symfony_requirements`. Fix it and all will work like a charm

Answer (score 2):

this might help you:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 bin/symfony_requirements
```

check if other directory and files need permission, for example in my case:

`sudo chown -R $USER web/`

was also needed.

furthermore if you had problem with cache and logs you may find following useful:

```
 rm -rf var/logs
 rm -rf var/cache
 rm -rf vendor
```

and then using `composer install`